# Encoding issue while integrating Moment JS library

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, momentjs

I have recently integrated MomentJS library into my application and have been running into a weird issue. Browser I have to use is IE9.

When I launch the application for the first time with zh-cn locale, I see a few junk characters in place of date and time. When I log out and log in again, then the characters load properly.

I check the encoding on screen and see it is UTF-8 both times. The issue is not consistent. I am at a loss as in what should I do to debug or get to the root of this issue. Any pointers about what I should check would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For integrating the MomentJS library, instead of

`<script src="moment-with-locales.js"></script>`

use this

`<script src="moment-with-locales.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>`