# Impossible to use accents with momentJS

Tags: character-encoding, momentjs

I'm want to create a Moment using the 'MMMM YYYY' format. It does work when the month name does not contain any accent, but fail and detect an invalid month when the month name contain an accent.

**Working**

```
var myMoment = moment('Janvier 2015', 'MMMM YYYY');
```

**Not working**

```
var myMoment = moment('Février 2015', 'MMMM YYYY');
var myMoment = moment('Août 2015', 'MMMM YYYY');
```

I'm trying to force utf-8 but doesn't seems to be enough

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to write it in HTML as static text.
This guarantees that the editor uses UTF-8.

JavaScript could specify `<script charset=...>` too.

Alternative:

```
'F\u00E9vrier' and 'Ao\u00FBt'.
```

CharMap shows the codes.

Comment: Appreciate the help however, I was already using <script charset=...> and using Ao\u00FBt is giving me the exact same error. And it wouldn't solve my probleme because i'm actually getting "Août" by doing moment().add(1, 'month').format('MMMM') ...

Comment: `<script src="moment-with-langs.js" charset="UTF-8" ></script>`? Other than diving into the JS sources I have no idea.

Comment: Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215002/encoding-issue-while-integrating-moment-js-library